# Wattage on ceiling socket?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I noticed on most ceiling sockets the wattage is listed as 660 or 600 Watts. Why is it listed this way and what is the safe amount of wattage that can be used by bulb in such socket. Picture of what I am talking about is below[image]

Comment: That is what it is tested to. It would probably be safe for somewhat more, but normally the lamp would not approach that. Do you want to put in a lamp which is greater than 600 W? If you are putting these in be careful not to overtighten the screws--you can crack the ceramic.

Comment: I was thinking of a 100 watt led bulb. Would that be ok?

Comment: A "100 Watt LED bulb" usually means an LED bulb which gives light equivalent to a 100 W incandescent. This would actually consume about 20 W of power and so is 30 times below the limit for this type of socket. We have four of these ceramic bases in our kitchen with just that type of bulb and it works great.

Comment: These ceramic bases are cheap, but in US design practice are usually used in a closet, a storeroom, or garage. But I think think they can be used in the living space as a minimalist or retro design element. We have 4 of them in the kitchen on a pressed tin ceiling. They are located at the corners of a 5 ft square in an 8 ft x 8 ft area of pressed tin panels. The one drawback to having exposed bulbs on an 8 ft high ceiling is that one could break a bulb while manipulating a wet mop, especially with a commercial type mop squeezer wringer. Wish we had 9 ft or 10 ft ceilings.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, light fixtures are limited due to a housing (creating a confined space), or flammable material near the bulb  (such as a lamp shade). In the case of a simple "keyless" socket, neither is the case, so wattage (heat) tolerance is higher.